# Docker can not create volume /usr/share/nginx/html/image

Tags: docker

I am trying to set physical path to my volume that used in Spring Boot project with docker.
When i try to up my docker-compose it shows error

```
Cannot start service sb-service: error while creating mount source path '/usr/share/nginx/html/image': mkdir /usr/share/nginx: read-only file system
```

I set chmod 777 to

```
/usr/share/nginx 
/usr/share/nginx/html
/usr/share/nginx/html/image
```

also i created image folder with `sudo mkdir image` as well.

This is my docker compose file

```
sb-service:
     image: sb-service
     container_name: sb-service
     environment:
               SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: 'jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3306/ECommerce?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false'
     ports: 
      - '8085:8085'
     expose: 
      - '8085'
     volumes:
           - /usr/share/nginx/html/image:/root/images
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034955/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-data-db-on-mac) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526219/docker-mkdir-read-only-file-system) may help?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [Docker - mkdir read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526219/docker-mkdir-read-only-file-system) this and removed old docker snap. Purged all docker things and reinstall all of them. Problem solved