# Docker: error while creating mount source path. How can i fix it?

Tags: docker

Tks all, idk why, but now its working

I am learning to use docker. I am trying to mount a host directory in a Docker container:

> >docker run -it -v /Users/Kell/Desktop/data:/home/data 77

And this is error: docker:

> Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/Users/Kell/Desktop/data': mkdir /Users: file exists.

**I use Windows and Docker 20.10.12, 77 is the imageID**
I tried on another disk and tried many other ways but it is still not working. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the `77`?

Comment: What's the host OS? Windows? Mac? What's the target OS? Linux? Are you using the latest version of docker?

Comment: I use windows and docker 20.10.12, 77 is imageID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you learning docker from scratch it is recommended to use `--mount` and not `-v` anymore: [Mount > v](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)

The syntax of `--mount` and `-v` differs, so here you' find both: [How to mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#start-a-container-with-a-bind-mount)

Path style in Windows depends on the console you are using. Some are just working in one and not in another.

Windows-Style: `docker run --rm -ti -v C:\Users\user\work:/work alpine`

Pseudo-Linux-Style in Windows:  `docker run --rm -ti -v /c/Users/user/work:/work alpine` as well as `//c/`

Inside WSL: `docker run --rm -ti -v /mnt/c/Users/user/work:/work alpine`

See: [Path conversion in Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/troubleshoot/#path-conversion-on-windows)

Comment: Tks, I just learned it today

Answer (score 3):

If you installed Docker with snap e.g. during installing Ubuntu, you may have a pathing issue. In that case, Docker cannot write to your path.
Try a path in /home directory. Something like /home/docker/.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489929/425024