# Mounting a volume on host in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-run

I am trying to mount a directory that exist on the host to a docker container.  First I created a volume to that directory, then I tell the container at run time to mount to it.  I have yet to get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?  The host is a ubuntu linux box.  The container is apache:latest..

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 --opt device=/var/www/wasql wasql2
    wasql2
docker run -p 8020:80 -p 2220:22 --network dockernet --mount src=wasql2,target=/var/www/wasql/ -it wasql.image /bin/bash
    docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/wasql2/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount /var/www/wasql:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/wasql2/_data, data: iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777: invalid argument.
```

Comment: Other questions have cited problems using Ubuntu's Snap packaging system for Docker; one example is [Docker - mkdir read-only file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526219/docker-mkdir-read-only-file-system).  Does using APT instead of Snap for installing Docker work better?  If the directory exists on the host already, can you use a plain Docker bind mount `docker run -v /var/www/wasql:/var/www/wasql` without the named volume?

Comment: I added the directory to to the Dockerfile (RUN mkdir /var/www/wasql)  and rebuild image.  Now I get the following:  docker run -p 8020:80 -p 2220:22 --network dockernet -v /var/www/wasql:/var/www/wasql/ -it wasql.image
-bash: root@dper6301:/home/slloyd/dockers#: No such file or directory

Comment: It WORKED!! :)  I had to unstall docker that was installed in the ubuntu install via snap, install using https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and reboot.  Then it works :  Thank you!